# Can't Run Putty on Ubuntu 22.10

Tags: 22.10, putty

```
    (putty:7413): Gtk-CRITICAL **: 22:5*:*9.028: gtk_box_gadget_distribute: assertion 'size >= 0' failed in GtkScrollbar

(putty:7413): Gtk-CRITICAL **: 22:5*:*9.028: gtk_box_gadget_distribute: assertion 'size >= 0' failed in GtkScrollbar

(putty:7413): Gtk-CRITICAL **: 22:5*:*9.028: gtk_box_gadget_distribute: assertion 'size >= 0' failed in GtkScrollbar
```

this error come out in terminal when i try run putty, i can't run  putty in ubuntu 22.10, anyone have fix ?? i try change font also just give me the same result.

however when i try run sudo putty in my terminal i can run it but still with same error above, why can't i run normally by just clicking an teh shortcut ??

Comment: Those errors appear even if it is working.  Can you please [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1456689/edit) your question and add the output of `ls -al $(which putty)`?

Comment: it give me this result with the command u give me -rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 12****2 May 31  2022 /usr/bin/putty

Comment: i remove and reinstall so many time already still have the same result only can run with sudo putty but not but clicking at the shortcut

Comment: The ownership of the `~/.putty` directory is probably incorrect then if it only runs with `sudo`.  Please run `sudo chown -R $USER: ~/.putty`

Answer (score 1):

Same problem.
Resolved with change in "Fonts" from 'server:fixed' to 'FreeMono' - it seems that is the only font who work

more information
https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1905268